# How to use Rust cargo through JFrog Artifactory proxy repository?

Tags: rust, artifactory, rust-cargo

I am trying to set up cargo to use an Artifactory proxy to crates.io registry.
Artifactory team in my company set it up for me based on [official documentation from JFrog](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/remote-cargo-repositories)

The instructions "Set me up" in Artifactory say to create a [`Config.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html), I create it with the exact configuration they provide, but nothing seems to work, I am not able to install anything via Cargo.
This is what I get:

```
Updating `artifactory` index
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
error: failed to fetch `https://<AF_URL>/artifactory/git/crates-io-cargo-proxy.git`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `git fetch --force --update-head-ok 'https://artifacts.rbi.tech/artifactory/git/crates-io-cargo-proxy.git' '+HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'` (exit status: 128)
```

And if I switch off the `git-fetch-with-cli`, I get this:

```
Updating `artifactory` index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): early EOF; class=Net (12); code=Eof (-20)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): early EOF; class=Net (12); code=Eof (-20)
error: failed to fetch `https://<AF_URL>/artifactory/git/crates-io-cargo-proxy.git`

Caused by:
  network failure seems to have happened
  if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  early EOF; class=Net (12); code=Eof (-20)
```

I tried playing around with many different options in `Config.toml` as well as env variables, but I was not able to make it work.

Is there anyone who has some experience with this?

Comment: This looks like an error in the network setup - have you searched for 'jfrog spurious network error'? Doing so gives a couple of leads (ssh-agent setup, local firewall, ...). Without concrete information, any answer will be hit-or-miss, I'm afraid

Comment: I also wonder if this is a better question for the vendor than for the internet at large...

Comment: @Marijan I'm curious if this was working for you before at some point or if this is the first time you're setting it up. If this was working for you before, has your Artifactory instance updated recently?